# Restsharp Adding Content-Type and Content-Disposition to Binary Streams

Tags: amazon-s3, restsharp

We are participating in a process where we provide a vendor with AWS S3 SignedURLs that allow them to upload files to an S3 bucket.

The process is quite simple:

1. They request a signedurl from us via an API / Lambda function we've published in AWS.
2. We return an S3 signedurl.
3. They use the signedurl to POST a binary file (in this case, a compressed .zip file).

While we don't have all of their code, they shared this snippet regarding the actual POST operation.  (interesting to note, they're using the **PUT** method...not sure if that matters).

The problem occurs in Step 3.  Their service uploads the binary file and, if we change the binary file to .txt, we see the following additional elements have been added to the .zip.

```
--6de81f1b-be80-44de-8a14-7e023c92fcf3
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="H22101_0031_087.zip"
```

This alters the structure of the .zip file considerably, causes checksum operations to fail and prevents us from decompressing the file...essentially it isn't a valid .zip unless we strip these additional elements out.

The code responsible for posting the binary is quite simple:

```
var dataFileUploadRequest = new RestRequest();
dataFileUploadRequest.Method = Method.Put;
dataFileUploadRequest.AddFile("file", sdpData, documentFileName);
dataFileUploadRequest.RequstFormat = DataFormat.Binary;
```

They implemented a workaround by using httpclient instead of restsharp...however, we would like to better understand why this is happening.

Does anyone know why restsharp's libraries would append this additional Content-Type, Content-Disposition...and even that strange guid (which appears to be a sort of transaction id) around the .zip's binary contents?

Comment: For added context, we just removed the restsharp and used standard httpclient.  Would still like to know how restsharp is adding these additional elements...

Comment: It's a standard multipart form data. I am not sure what you do with `HttpClient`, but if you add the `StreamContent` to your request and set the `ContentDisposition` content header, it would be like this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST